# How we set value in single text field with character and numeric but character value only read able using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In My html code

i take one input field suppose this input filed have value='100 meter'
 so 
 i wont result should according to value which is define in input tag but 'meter' is only read.

Comment: Might be useful to actually provide your HTML and JavaScript code, at lest some of it, and elaborate on what the problem is and what the intended behavior is.

Answer (score 0):

According to the information you provided. You want to retrieve last word from the value which is unit. In javascript you can do as follows.

```
split_value = $("input field div").val().split(' ')
unit = split_value[split_value.length - 1]
```